# Break XOR type encryption with whole Known text from virus

Tags: encryption, cryptography, xor, virus

I was hit by a ransomware infection that encrypts the first 512 bytes at the top of the file and puts them at the bottom. Upon looking at the encrypted text it seems to be some type of XOR cipher. I know the whole plain text  of one of the files that was encrypted, so i figured in theory i should be able to xor it to get the key to decrypt the rest of my files. Well i am having a very hard time with this because i don't understand how the creator xor'ed it really. Im thinking he would use a binaryreader to read the first 512 bytes into an array, XOR it, and replace it. But does that mean he XOR'ed it in HEX? or Decimal? Im quite confused at this point, but i believe i am simply missing something.

I have tried Xor Tool with python, and everything it attempts to crack looks like non sense. I also tried a python script called Unxor that you give the known plain text to, but the dump file it outputs is always blank.

**Good Header file dump:**
[Good-Header.bin](https://www.dropbox.com/s/v68qz2qrm6n2yih/good-header.bin)

**Encrypted Header file dump:**
[Enc-Header.bin](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wp3y1drwy82sjco/enc_header.bin)

This may not be the best file example to see the XOR pattern, but its the only file i have that also has the original header 100% before encryption. In other headers where there is more changes the encrypted header changes with it.

Any advice on a method i should try, or application i should use to try and take this further? Thanks so much for your help!

P.S Stackoverflow yelled at me when i tried to post 4 links because im so new, so if you would rather see the hex dumps on pastebin than download the header files, please let me no. The files are in no way malicious, and are only the extracted 512 bytes and not a whole file.

Comment: I've generated a generic answer for you to get a better understanding of the subject. Because of the low chance of success and the fact that the result will only be applicable to you, it's unlikely that anybody is going to do the deciphering for you.

Comment: There is no xor pattern to see. If there is always other stream that was used to encrypt file headers it is considered to be unbreakable unless streams are related like same for instance. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad

Comment: Owlstead, Thanks for the answer :) and no one asked anyone to do any deciphering for me, as you can see above i asked for advice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To recover the keystream XOR the plaintext bytes with the cyphertext bytes.  Do this with two different files so you can see if the ransomware is using the same keystream or a different keystream for each file.

If it is using the same keystream (unlikely) then your problem is solved.  If the keystreams are different, then your easiest solution is to restore the affected files from backups.  You did keep backups, didn't you?  Alternatively research the particular infection you have got and see if anyone else has broken that particular variant, so you can derive the key(s) they used and hence regenerate the required keystreams.

If you have a lot of money then a data recovery firm might be able to help you, but they will certainly charge.

Comment: Well i can tell the same key is used per file because in 2 different pdf files the marker "%PDF" encrypted looks the exact same. Do you happen to know of any .net code that would help me xor a binary file with known text? i found a few but they all add additional things in the function. Thanks

Comment: You do not XOR with text, you XOR with the **binary representation** of the text.  In effect you read the file as data bytes, not text.  Treat it as a byte[], not as a string.  You XOR two byte[] with each other to produce a third byte[], the keystream.

Comment: @user3546043, the same [block of] plaintext will always result in the same [block of] ciphertext even with a strong symmetric block cipher, — provided that the cipher operates in electronic codebook (ECB) mode, i. e. without initialization vector. So your observation proves practically nothing.

Comment: So i kind of hit a break through i think today (Maybe?). So i took Rossum's advice and i Xor'ed the first byte of the encrypted file with the first byte of the original file. I was then able to take the result byte and i Xor'ed it on the first byte of multiple encrypted files and it always produced the first letter of the marker for that file. But i do remember the person i was testing with earlier saying that the next byte  has to do with the last one (CFB i think?) so i cant just XOR it like the first?

Comment: @user3546043, block ciphers operate on blocks rather than on bytes or bits. A “block” is, for example, a sequence of 64 bits, which may be split in a pair of 32-bit “limbs”. A Feistel-like cipher perturbates limbs by mixing them with several “substitution boxes” and a “round subkey” — up to several dozens of rounds per single block. So it's not that simple as `c = p ^ k` you expected. Even with a 8-bit key like “A”, output will look totally random.

Comment: Ok, so even though we can get back the first byte of every encrypted file, there is something much more complicated brewing ahead is what your saying

Answer (score 0):

A rule of thumb to tell a decent cipher from a toy cipher is to encrypt a highly compressible file and try to compress it in its encrypted form: a dumb cipher will produce a file with a level of entropy similar to that of the original one, so the encrypted file will compress as well as the original one; on the other side, a good cipher (even without an initialization vector) will produce a file that will look like a random garbage and thus will not compress at all.

When I compressed your *Enc-Header.bin* of 512 bytes with PKZIP, the output was also 512 bytes, so the cipher is not as dumb as you expected — bad luck. (But it does not mean that the malware has no weak spots at all.)

Comment: I did not know this, Thanks for this useful information!